# How does OAuth Custom Scope work?

Tags: oauth

I was trying to find a flow diagram how OAuth Custom Scopes works but found very limited documentation on this. Could anyone please explain what it does and how it works?

Comment: @Anvijit: Did you get any thing regarding this?